Search all of second dataframe for Column A of strings in first dataframe and fill Column B with the value of Column A in second dataframe
I see lots of similar questions but not quite my situation.
I have 2 dataframes, each with many many columns. A very simplified reproduction is:
df1:
   serial_num    name    
 0  39jr93j      Phyl       
 1  <NA>         Gil       
 2  21pr12n      Ann 

df2:
   serial_num    name    alternate_nombre  different_name   nm_alternate
 0  5c2v40l      Jill       Jyl.            Jill Smith.       Gil Smyth
 1  21pr12n      Karen      Caren.          Karen Ann.        Caryn Anne
 2  39jr93j      Phyllis    Fillus          Phil              Phyllus

Desired result:
   serial_num    name    
 0  39jr93j      Phyl       
 1  5c2v40l      Gil       
 2  21pr12n      Ann 

DF1 is missing some of the serial numbers but the only name column in df1 may not be the same spelling used in df2. I want to look up all the rows that are missing df1['serial_num'] in df2 to fill it in. But in df2, there are a significant number of alternate name columns such that it's not feasible to itemize which columns to look in. And the name in df1 may be a substring of a name/alternate name in df2. So I want to look in the whole df2 as though the df1['name'] was a substring.
Then I want to fill in the corresponding df1['serial_num'] with the df2['serial_num'].
I can't wrap my head around how to do this without iterating over the rows.
I have created a subset of rows that are missing df['serial_num'] with the following:
missing_serials = df1[df1['serial_num'].isnull()]
I see some solutions for searching a whole dataframe for a substring looking like this:
df2[df2.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('specific static substring', case=False).any(), axis=1)]
But I can't seem to figure out how to replace the 'specific static substring' with my missing_serials['name'] without iterating through the rows or how to combine my missing_serials and df2 when I can't predict which column will match. I'm starting to wonder if using the missing_serials sub-dataframe is even the right way to go because I don't know how i'll get the values back into df1. Maybe there's some kind of df1['serial_num'].fillna approach that's better?

Personally, I see this option using df1.apply.
Then we will make a temporary DataFrame with unique combinations of rows and values for all possible columns in df2 that may contain matches. Next, we will search through all columns using str.contains and merge with df1.
df2_long = pd.concat([df2[['serial_num']], df2.drop(columns=['serial_num']).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)], axis=1)
df2_long.columns = ['serial_num', 'name_variant']

A function for finding matches and replacing serial_num:
def find_serial_num(row, df2_long):
    if pd.isnull(row['serial_num']):
        match = df2_long[df2_long['name_variant'].str.contains(row['name'], case=False, na=False)]
        if not match.empty:
            return match.iloc[0]['serial_num']
    return row['serial_num']

At the end, we apply the function to df1:
df1['serial_num'] = df1.apply(find_serial_num, df2_long=df2_long, axis=1)


This will fill in the missing serial_num values in df1 based on matching any column in df2 where the name in df1 is a substring.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'serial_num': ['39jr93j', np.nan, '21pr12n'],
    'name': ['Phyl', 'Gil', 'Ann']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'serial_num': ['5c2v40l', '21pr12n', '39jr93j'],
    'name': ['Jill', 'Karen', 'Phyllis'],
    'alternate_nombre': ['Jyl.', 'Caren.', 'Fillus'],
    'different_name': ['Jill Smith.', 'Karen Ann.', 'Phil'],
    'nm_alternate': ['Gil Smyth', 'Caryn Anne', 'Phyllus']
})

# Function to find matching serial_num
def find_serial_num(name, df2):
    for _, row in df2.iterrows():
        if row.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and name in x).any():
            return row['serial_num']
    return np.nan

# Create a copy of df1 to avoid modifying the original dataframe
df1_filled = df1.copy()

# Apply the function to rows where serial_num is missing
df1_filled.loc[df1_filled['serial_num'].isnull(), 'serial_num'] = df1_filled.loc[df1_filled['serial_num'].isnull(), 'name'].apply(lambda name: find_serial_num(name, df2))


Maybe not the best solution, but this avoid iteration:
df2 = df2.set_index("serial_num").stack().reset_index(name="name_join")
df2["name_join"] = df2["name_join"].apply(lambda x: x.split())
df2 = df2.explode("name_join")
df2["name_join"] = df2["name_join"].str.replace(r"\W", "", regex=True).str.lower()

df1 = pd.merge(
    df1.assign(name_join=df1["name"].str.lower()),
    df2,
    how="left",
    on="name_join",
    suffixes=("", "_fill"),
)
df1["serial_num"] = df1["serial_num"].fillna(df1["serial_num_fill"])
df1 = df1.drop(columns=["serial_num_fill", "level_1", "name_join"])

   serial_num  name
0    39jr93j  Phyl
1    5c2v40l   Gil
2    21pr12n   Ann

